# How to run ElectronJs without a UI?

Tags: node.js, electron

As well as a UI, I'd like users to have the option of passing in command line options to my tool and for it to output the response to the command line (eg manually or in cron).

Even without creating a window, the UI gets going (eg taskbar on the mac), and on a linux back-end server with no UI libraries it crashes completely.

Is there a way I can avoid having to ship two apps separately, and also more annoyingly using electron to package up one exe, and something like pkg for the other?

Thanks!

Comment: Electron requires X11. See https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/testing-on-headless-ci.md . Obviously, if you want it to be CLI that runs in any server environment, this won't work. It depends on your app how actually may do this. Why would you install entire Electron app to the server if you need only Node?

Comment: Thanks. It's actually more for home users, and I was hoping to get to the point where the same app would work on something like a pi with CLI or UI depending on user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a bundling tool like [EncloseJS](http://enclosejs.com/) to wrap your Electron application. This would allow you to write a CLI interface. You would then need to move the code that does the actual work to a shared library that both Electron and your CLI can use. You could then introduce a `--headless` flag that would simply not start the Electron app, while omitting the flag would start the app as usual.

Comment: Thanks. Quick note to others that EncloseJS is deprecated, and https://github.com/zeit/pkg is the future of this project.